# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HacksStorageService: ([object Object], ?). at syntaxError

Tags: angular, service

I am instantiating 3 services in app.module.ts

```
  providers: [AuthService, HackService, HacksStorageService],
```

HackService is as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class HackService {

  hacksChanged = new Subject<Hack[]>();
  hacks: Hack[] = [];

  constructor(
    private hacksStorageService: HacksStorageService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

etc.

}
```

HacksStorageService is as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class HacksStorageService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private hackService: HackService
  ) {}

    fetchHacks(token: string, uid: string) {
        this.httpClient.get<Hack[]>(`https://hackaton-refactor.firebaseio.com//${uid}/hacks.json`, {
            params: new HttpParams().set('auth', token),
    })
    .pipe( map( (hacks: Hack[]) => { return hacks = (hacks === null) ? [] : hacks } ) )
    .subscribe( (hacks: Hack[]) => this.hackService.setHacks(hacks) )
  }

  storeHacks(uid: String, token: string, hacks: Hack[]) {
    this.httpClient.put(`https://hackaton-app-8a11a.firebaseio.com/${uid}/hacks.json`, hacks, {
      params: new HttpParams().set('auth', token)
        })
  }
}
```

Angular is failing in the HacksStorageService, he keep telling me:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for HacksStorageService: ([object Object], ?)
```

I don't get why he can not inject the instance of HackService, when I am providing it in the app.module.ts

Any help?

Comment: `HacksStorageService  <-> HackService <-> HacksStorageService`

Comment: Because you have a circular depedency

Comment: so, we should never inject other services in a service, right?

Comment: @AlbertMunichMar it's best practice, but you should be able to solve this particular issue using `forwardRef`. But not going to post an answer, because better would be to refactor.

Comment: I refactored the code, smaller methods. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have circular dependency in your code . try to put services separately and use them in component by importing. do not import  `HackService` here

```
@Injectable()
export class HacksStorageService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private hackService: HackService <<-- circular dependency. 
  ) {}

    fetchHacks(token: string, uid: string) {
        this.httpClient.get<Hack[]>(`https://hackaton-refactor.firebaseio.com//${uid}/hacks.json`, {
            params: new HttpParams().set('auth', token),
    })
    .pipe( map( (hacks: Hack[]) => { return hacks = (hacks === null) ? [] : hacks } ) )
    .subscribe( (hacks: Hack[]) => this.hackService.setHacks(hacks) )
  }

  storeHacks(uid: String, token: string, hacks: Hack[]) {
    this.httpClient.put(`https://hackaton-app-8a11a.firebaseio.com/${uid}/hacks.json`, hacks, {
      params: new HttpParams().set('auth', token)
        })
  }
}
```